# How to compile Linux kernel 5.19.8 with symbols and debugging enabled?

Tags: linux

In the config file, all I can find is the option "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_NONE". I am not sure what I should set this to, and what other config options must be set in order for the kernel to be compiled with symbols for debugging. I am trying to use GDB to debug the kernel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking at the configuration file directly, you should use the configuration tools, *e.g.* `make menuconfig`. To build with debug information, you need to enable `DEBUG_KERNEL` (“Kernel debugging”), then under “Debug information”, choose “Rely on the toolchain's implicit default DWARF version”. You‘ll then see `DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT` in your `.config` file.